# Getting "Change" event for a text field whose contents is changed by jQuery

Tags: live, onchange, jquery

I've made some pretty checkboxes using some pretty simple jQuery

HTML

```
<span class="iconElement checkBox" id="update_Check"></span>
<input type="text" id="update" name="update" value="0" class="hidden savedData" />
```

JS

```
$('.checkBox').live('click', function (e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled') != true) {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked')
        var thisValue = parseInt($(this).next().val());
        var newValue = (thisValue - 1) * (-1); // enusures the output is either 1 or 0, [ (1-1)*-1=0 and (0-1)*-1 =1 ]
        $(this).next().val(newValue);
    };
});
```

This is simply a span with a nice CSS background sprite, which when clicked changes toggles it's "checked" class, adjusting the CSS sprite from a "Tick" to an empty box. At the same time it also changes the content of a text field (hidden by CSS class 'hidden') to a 1 or a 0 to indicate whether the box is checked.

It has to have this 1 or 0 as when the data is passed to the next stage I have to have a value, an unchecked checkbox sends no value.

This all works fine!

BUT... I also need to be able to detect the "change" event of the hidden text field.

This is to be controlled by the "savedData" class.

```
$('.savedData').live('change', function () {
    // do stuff now we know this has been changed
});
```

I could of course include this within the "click" event in the code above, but that's not practical for the application.

It seems that the "change" even is only trigger by elements which are changed by the keyboard or mouse, anything changed by jQuery is not being flagged.

Initially I was using hidden input type and thought that was the issue, but have changed them all to text type now and the problem is still there!

Any tips?!

Comment: Those who follow jQuery questions are probably sick of me already, but hey, SOMEBODY has got to say it! -> `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, and was frowned upon even before that. You will get better performance and current-standards code by binding your events with `.on()`. Instead of setting document as listener (which is what `.live()` does), I have no doubt that you can find a much closer ancestor on your page.

Comment: I actually tried changing everything over to `.on()` today and lots of stuff stopped working. Primarily, handling events with elements produced by jQuery. ie, I have an extending form which has one row of elements in it, when the row is completed, jQuery adds another row, functions bound to the new row would not work with `.on()` so I went back to `live()`. Tried reading the docs, but couldn't see why this was happening and don't have time to faff with it! Docs implied it would work... but...!

Comment: Jamie, I have no doubt that it a syntax issue either in terms of identifying your selector or not passing enough arguments (if you used `$('.savedData').on('change', function() {})` it won't work: that's not the translation). I try to explain it a bit here: http://gregpettit.ca/2011/jquery-events-its-on/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that the "change" even is only trigger by elements which are changed by the keyboard or mouse, anything changed by jQuery is not being flagged.

Yes, that is correct. That is precisely how this works. Only changes made by the user trigger event handlers: programmatic changes do not. The only way to trigger them is to do so yourself:

```
$(this).next().val(newValue).change();
```

The [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change) triggers a `change` event on the element, so the handler will be called.